# jquery-modal open with button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use [jquery-modal](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal), and evoke it with buttonclick. But when i do this, i get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'blur' of undefined
```

HTML & JavaScript

```
<button>Button</button>
...
<form id="login-form" class="modal">
  <div>Test</div>
</form>
...
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#login-form').modal();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#login-form').modal();
    });
});
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZVybfbm1

jquery.modal.css and jquery.modal.js is from https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal

modal is working when I click link, but errors when click button

Comment: open "jquery.modal.js" and find for "this.anchor.blur()" and comment it.

Comment: bro there is a problem with the library, it is only compatible with anchor tag, so you need to comment it.

Answer (score 0):

You can give id for button and use that id to trigger click event.

```
<button id="loginButton">Button</button>

$('#loginButton').click(function() {
  $('#login-form').modal();
});
```

Comment: It is not the selector problem, its working just fine